# 'InfobipApiClient' is not defined

Tags: python, infobip, infobip-api

```
 
 File "python.py", line 31, in <module>
 infobip_client = InfobipApiClient(api_key=INFOBIP_API_KEY)
 NameError: name 'InfobipApiClient' is not defined
```

im creating a python telegram bot . which have capability to send message to a user.
i get this error . im still a infobip kiddie
please help to solve

> File "python.py", line 31, in 
> infobip_client = InfobipApiClient(api_key=INFOBIP_API_KEY) NameError: name 'InfobipApiClient' is not defined

i think i missed a import module . i dont know what it is .

Answer (score 0):

First install the library:

```
pip install infobip-api-python-client
```

Then in code import it:

```py
from infobip_api_client.api_client import ApiClient as InfobipApiClient
```

More details in: https://github.com/infobip/infobip-api-python-client